# Calling an interface function faster than calling a member function directly?

Tags: performance, fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I came across a strange behavior of both `gfortran` and `ifort` during an investigation on why `reshape` is much slower than a naive implementation using loops:

I defined an interface `my_reshape` for two reshaping functions (`reshape3Dto1D`, and `reshape1Dto3D`). When calling the interface function instead of the member function directly, I noticed a speed-up of 10-40%! Changing the order of the calls, the level optimization, and even the compiler did not change this behavior.

Am I making a mistake, or does anyone have an explanation for this?

Here is the (simplified) code:

reshapetest_simple.F90:

```
module test
  interface my_reshape
    module procedure :: reshape3Dto1D
  end interface
contains
  function reshape3Dto1D( mat, dims )
    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
    implicit none
    integer, parameter  :: cp = REAL64
    real(cp),intent(in) :: mat(:,:,:)
    integer,intent(in)  :: dims(1)
    real(cp)            :: reshape3Dto1D(dims(1))
    integer             :: x,y,z, i

    i=0
    do z=1,size(mat,3)
      do y=1,size(mat,2)
        do x=1,size(mat,1)
          i=i+1
          reshape3Dto1D(i) = mat(x,y,z)
        enddo ! y
      enddo ! y
    enddo !z
  end function
end module

program changeDim
  use test
  use omp_lib
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: cp = REAL64

  real(REAL64) :: t1, t2, t3, t4
  integer,parameter   :: dimX=100, dimY=100, dimZ=100
  integer,parameter   :: dimProduct = dimX*dimY*dimZ
  integer             :: stat
  real(cp),pointer,contiguous    :: matrix3d(:,:,:), matrix1d(:)

  allocate( matrix3d(dimX,dimY,dimZ), matrix1d(dimProduct), stat=stat )
  if (stat/=0) stop 'Cannot allocate memory';
  call random_number(matrix3d)
  matrix1d = 0._cp

  ! (1) Naive copy using a function
  t1 = omp_get_wtime()
  matrix1d = reshape3Dto1D( matrix3d, [ dimProduct ] )
  t2 = omp_get_wtime()
  ! (2) Reshape
  matrix1d = reshape( matrix3d, [ dimProduct ] )
  t3 = omp_get_wtime()
  ! (3) Same as (1), but using the interface
  matrix1d = my_reshape( matrix3d, [ dimProduct ] )
  t4 = omp_get_wtime()

  write(*,*) 'Reshape:             ',t3-t2
  write(*,*) 'Naive fct direct:    ',t2-t1
  write(*,*) 'Naive fct interface: ',t4-t3

  deallocate( matrix3d, matrix1d )
end program
```

I used `gfortran 4.8.1`, and `ifort 13.1.3`. The binaries were compiled using

```
ifort -o reshape-ifort -openmp reshapetest_simple.F90 -O3
gfortran -o reshape-gfortran -fopenmp reshapetest_simple.F90 -O3
```

and gave the following results:

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./reshape-gfortran 
 Reshape:                6.8527370000310839E-003
 Naive fct direct:       5.0175579999631736E-003
 Naive fct interface:    4.6131109999123510E-003
OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./reshape-ifort 
 Reshape:               3.495931625366211E-003
 Naive fct direct:      5.089998245239258E-003
 Naive fct interface:   3.136873245239258E-003
```

BTW: I know that for this kind reshaping one is better of using pointers to avoid copying the array...

Comment: I noticed similar behaviour when calling LAPACK routines from MKL. Using the F95 interface was faster than using the routine itself.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I replaced `omp_get_wtime()` by `MPI_Wtime()` and `cpu_time()`, respectively (and removed `-[f]openmp`) - but got the same results. So, this has probably nothing to do with OpenMP.

Comment: Tried this with gfortran, only with multiple iterations of each routine for better timing. I found that the difference was too small to notice if I changed `reshape3Dto1D` to be a subroutine that took both arrays as arguments, gave both arrays the contiguous attribute in that routine, and made both arrays static in the main program. If I did this and had one array static and one allocatable, the timings changed, but both interfaces still took about the same time. If I did this and made both arrays allocatable, suddenly I was able to reproduce this again.

Comment: Oh, I was using gfortran 4.7.3, and I could not reproduce this with `-O0`. So the long and short of it is that I have no idea, but I suspect that this is an optimization bug on gfortran's part. Maybe it has something to do with gfortran's ability to prove that the two arrays are non-overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

#### Influencing factors

This behavior has to do with the problem size (100x100x100) and the use of `real,pointer,contiguous`.

#### Experiment

Replace

```
real(cp),pointer,contiguous :: matrix3d(:,:,:), matrix1d(:)
```

with

```
real(cp),  allocatable      :: matrix3d(:,:,:), matrix1d(:)
```

and the behavior will more or less go away, in my test completely with increasing dimX, dimY and dimZ to 200.

#### Timing with GNU Fortran 4.7.3

pointer, dim = 100

```
Reshape:                5.5749416351318359E-003
Naive fct direct:       6.2539577484130859E-003
Naive fct interface:    2.8791427612304688E-003
```

allocatable, dim = 100

```
Reshape:                4.2719841003417969E-003
Naive fct direct:       1.4619827270507813E-003
Naive fct interface:    1.3799667358398438E-003
```

pointer, dim = 200

```
Reshape:                4.2979001998901367E-002
Naive fct direct:       5.7554006576538086E-002
Naive fct interface:    3.6303043365478516E-002
```

allocatable, dim = 200

```
Reshape:                4.3957948684692383E-002
Naive fct direct:       1.1255979537963867E-002
Naive fct interface:    1.1703014373779297E-002
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I started with `allocatable`s when I noticed the difference - the pointers are a relic of my tinkering. With increasing size, the effect indeed decreases. At all dimensions at 200 I still have a difference of ~5% for both `ifort` and `gfortran`.

Comment: BTW: The problems is present even when using static arrays.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce your results with other versions of `gfortran`: 4.7.3 (Ubuntu), or `4.7.1` (SUSE). The same for `ifort` 12.0.0 (some modifications due to missing Fortran 2003 features). In total, I tested it on four different machines (Intel and AMD). I'm at a loss here... Which compile options do you use?

Comment: gfortran-mp-4.7 -o reshape-gfortran -fopenmp reshapetest_simple.F90 -O3 , (OS X, compiler installed via MacPorts)